# how to Create list of lists to string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tree

I have a tree in the format of list in python and I need to convert it to Newick tree format.

Example Newick tree:

```
(B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4):0.5)
```

Its list of list representation in my implementation :

```
[[[b],0.2, [[c],0.3,[d],0.4],0.5]]
```

Normally join function can be used to convert list to str however, int this case, this list of list can also be list of list of list of list. There could be many inner loop, which we don't know the exact structure. How can I convert this list to Newick tree format as a string?

Comment: You need a recursive function to handle nested structures like this.

Answer (score 1):

Write a recursive function:

```
>>> def newick(data):
...     if not isinstance(data, list):
...         return str(data)
...     if len(data) == 1:
...         return newick(data[0])
...     return "(" + ",".join(
...         newick(a) + ":" + newick(b)
...         for a, b in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])
...     ) + ")"
...
>>> newick([[['B'],0.2, [['C'],0.3,['D'],0.4],0.5]])
'(B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4):0.5)'
```